# Alternative to base64 decode in powershell

Tags: windows, postgresql, powershell, kubernetes, minikube

I was following a guide to connect a database to kubernetes:
https://itnext.io/basic-postgres-database-in-kubernetes-23c7834d91ef

after installing Kubernetes (minikube) on Windows 10 64 bit:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

I am encountering an issue with 'base64' where the DB is trying to connect and store the password.  As PowerShell doesn't recognise it. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas how I could either fix this and still use windows or an alternative means that would enable me to continue with the rest of the guide?

Error Code:

```
base64 : The term 'base64' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:131
+ ... postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decod ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (base64:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default pos ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[Windows Powershell Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veiUJ.png)

Comment: BASE64 is just a string, one used to encode binary data as text. Powershell works with strings without problems. It also has functions to convert BASE64 strings to bytes and back. What code did you try, what's the actual error? Post the code and error as text in the question itself

Comment: I have updated the code as requested, 
the code I tried was:

export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default postgres-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode) 

from https://itnext.io/basic-postgres-database-in-kubernetes-23c7834d91ef

Answer (score 6):

The `base64` cli found in Mac OS and some *nix distros is not available on Windows.

You *could* write a small function named `base64` that mimics the behavior of the `base64` unix tool though:

```
function base64 {
  # enumerate all pipeline input
  $input |ForEach-Object {
    if($MyInvocation.UnboundArguments -contains '--decode'){
      # caller supplied `--decode`, so decode 
      $bytes = [convert]::FromBase64String($_)
      [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes)
    } else {
      # default mode, encode ascii text as base64
      $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($_)
      [convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
    }
  }
}
```

This should work as a drop-in replacement for conversion between ASCII/UTF7 text and base64:

```
PS ~> 'Hello, World!' |base64 --encode
SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==
PS ~> 'Hello, World!' |base64 --encode |base64 --decode
Hello, World!
```

---

To use with your existing scripts, simple dot-source a script with the function definition in your shell before executing the others:

```
PS ~> . .\path\to\base64.ps1
```

The above will work from a script as well. If you have a multi-line paste-aware shell (Windows' default Console Host with PSReadLine should be okay), you can also just paste the function definition directly into the prompt :)

Comment: It is not printing the result to the console for me, is this expected?

Comment: The function outputs a string. Perhaps you're redirecting the output? Or assigning it to a variable? Show me the full command you execute :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute command lines *on Windows* that were written for *Unix*-like platforms, both in terms of:

- the *external utilities* they expect (`base64`)
- the *shell syntax* they use (`export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(...)`; written for POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`).

[Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70710915/45375) shows you how to emulate a `base64` utility in PowerShell, and you may even be able to emulate the `export` shell command with additional, nontrivial effort, but not *all* cases can be handled that way, such as a command line that uses `\"` to escape `"` characters (this will break PowerShell's *syntax*, try `echo "3\" of snow."`).

Therefore, I suggest either running your commands as-is via [WSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux), if feasible, or taking the time to translate the command lines into *PowerShell-native equivalents*.